# Data is not replicated from Redis master to slaves

Tags: redis, replication, redis-cluster

I am connecting to a small Redis cluster hosted by AWS which is not sharded, it has just one master and 3 slaves. I have been having difficulty with replication, and this is a simple reproduction of what I tried.

My clusters:

```
172.28.52.18:6379> CLUSTER NODES
cc378ecb71d02c2495e219ce7043ea343eb91c1f 172.28.52.18:6379@1122 myself,slave 6ce7214224036cc42ba272486d9e8fe5d1b11875 0 1610811475000 2 connected
1e17d7794741c7db491a888dc2bca76590b52e64 172.28.53.83:6379@1122 slave 6ce7214224036cc42ba272486d9e8fe5d1b11875 0 1610811476195 2 connected
6ce7214224036cc42ba272486d9e8fe5d1b11875 172.28.53.213:6379@1122 master - 0 1610811474182 2 connected 0-16383
d780dfbb4d33275e50c098032d1cceb1cd368a65 172.28.52.180:6379@1122 slave 6ce7214224036cc42ba272486d9e8fe5d1b11875 0 1610811475189 2 connected
```

Connect directly to master (172.28.53.213 in the above output) and set some data:

```
$ redis-cli -h 172.28.53.213
172.28.53.213:6379> SET key1 value1
OK
```

Then connect to one of the slaves:

```
$ redis-cli -h 172.28.52.180
172.28.52.180:6379> GET key1 value1
(error) MOVED 9189 172.28.53.213:6379
```

There are no shards and as I see it:

1. All slots (0-16383) are owned by master
2. All of the slaves are connected to master
3. Everything is in sync

So I don't understand why I would be redirected to master. Shouldn't the slave have a copy?

I am aware that I can connect with `-c` so that redirects are followed automatically, but the whole point of replication should be that redirects aren't necessary!

Comment: Based on the close vote (suggesting this should be asked on serverfault) at least one person thinks this is a server configuration issue?

Comment: I would be happy with an answer like "your assumptions are correct, this appears to be a server configuration problem", if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally slave nodes will redirect clients to the authoritative master for the hash slot involved in a given command, however clients can use slaves in order to scale reads using the READONLY command.

You can read about it [here](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#scaling-reads-using-slave-nodes).

If you want to read from a replica you have to execute [READONLY](https://redis.io/commands/readonly) command on it. And to revert to old behaviour there is a command [READWRITE](https://redis.io/commands/readwrite).

Comment: What's the point of a replica if you can't read from it?

Comment: It is about availability. "Redis Cluster failure detection is used to recognize when a master or slave node is no longer reachable by the majority of nodes and then respond by promoting a slave to the role of master."

Comment: ok, but there's no point promoting a slave to master if the data isn't replicated there...

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I thought I tried READONLY and it hadn't worked. I must have done something wrong, because it does now.

Answer (score 1):

As a Redis newbee, I encountered a similar issue and came to this thread. But the answer doesn't tell why. Finally, I figured it out after reading the redis server log (specified by `logfile` in the config) of the slave node, and I hope my answer helps.

In my case, the root cause is that the slave config file does not enable `masterauth <password>` while the master node enables `requirepass <password>`. It is commented out. In the log, this error leads me to the solution,

```
Master does not understand REPLCONF listening-port: -NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

In the cluster mode, when a failover occurs, a slave node is promoted to a master node. Later when the failed original master node comes back, it becomes a slave node. So, if the original slave node enables `requirepass <password>`, remember to enable `masterauth <password>` in the original master node config too. Otherwise, after the failover, the replication from the new master to the new slave still fails.

And one more thing I learned is that I need to restart the redis node after editing the config file.